# server not working smoothly

Tags: linux, hardware, kernel, scsi

Hi I am getting this error message in log.

Please suggest something to fix this issue

```
Sep 6 06:19:17 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:17 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:17 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:17 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:17 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:19 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:19 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:19 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:19 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:19 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 Adaptec Storage Manager Agent: [418] Bad Block discovered: controller 1 (1a5f5dec).
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 last message repeated 2 times
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: START: smtp pid=4075 from=127.0.0.1
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: START: smtp pid=4076 from=127.0.0.1
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: EXIT: smtp status=1 pid=4075 duration=0(sec)
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: EXIT: smtp status=1 pid=4076 duration=0(sec)
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: START: smtp pid=4095 from=127.0.0.1
Sep 6 06:19:21 sa1 xinetd[6613]: EXIT: smtp status=1 pid=4095 duration=0(sec)
Sep 6 06:19:27 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:27 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:27 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:27 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:27 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:29 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:29 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:29 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:29 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:29 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:31 sa1 Adaptec Storage Manager Agent: [418] Bad Block discovered: controller 1 (1a5f5dec).
Sep 6 06:19:31 sa1 Adaptec Storage Manager Agent: [418] Bad Block discovered: controller 1 (1a5f5dec).
Sep 6 06:19:31 sa1 xinetd[6613]: START: smtp pid=4836 from=127.0.0.1
Sep 6 06:19:31 sa1 xinetd[6613]: START: smtp pid=4838 from=127.0.0.1
Sep 6 06:19:32 sa1 xinetd[6613]: EXIT: smtp status=1 pid=4836 duration=1(sec)
Sep 6 06:19:32 sa1 xinetd[6613]: EXIT: smtp status=1 pid=4838 duration=1(sec)
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: sda: Current: sense key: Hardware Error
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: Add. Sense: Internal target failure
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel:
Sep 6 06:19:45 sa1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 442457580
Sep 6 06:19:47 sa1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
```

Answer (score 2):

Your hard drive has failed. Replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Your /dev/sda has gone... replace it as soon as possibile.